# Armature bone duplicates itself when I rotate it in Pose Mode

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I create simple armature. As you can see in video, left bones copy itself when I rotate it but this does not happen for right bones. How do I solve it? I don't want that duplication.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hMT5.jpg

Comment: it kinda looks as if you had two bones selected when you start extruding, but well, that just from how it behaves after that, so idk